# Navigation in android app for updating of destination location

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, location

#### Scenario :

In my android app, I have a Google Map that is showing me my friend's location. My friend and I can move from their position and I still want to get him (finding friend's location/updated_location is not an issue). To reach him fast, I am implementing navigation functionality to it.

#### Question :

1. How can I implement navigation to Google Map? I heard about `OpenTripPlanner`, but I'm not sure if I can use it in Google Maps.
2. As my friend's and my location can change, I want to update the navigation path from my current location to his current location. (An Idea I have is to recalculate the path when friend's location changes).
3. I also want to implement voice navigation to my app. How can I get this?

Any suggestion which will satisfy above requirement will be appreciated.
Please suggest sample code and working functions that can be used.

Comment: This seems more like a list of requirements than a specific question. You have to put out a little more than just the idea to get help.

Comment: ok first of all I need to implement navigation. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on implementing a navigation `Polyline` to your `Google Maps API V2`:

[Google Maps API V2 Polyline Navigation](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

There you will find the needed method to get the navigation instruction from `Google Directions API` and to paint it on your map.

Comment: I am having 2 error in your blogpost code.
1.`progressDialog = DialogUtils.createProgressDialog(activity,activity.getString(R.string.getdata));
— `DialogUtils` is undefined. Is there any package I need to download or need to create manually?
2.`GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`
—`getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined. Although I have already import these 2 reference :
`import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`
Please help!

Comment: I have updated the code in the guide and gave you an answer in the blog post.

Comment: I still having problem in adding jar files in Android Dependencies. please check your blog.

Comment: Hi Emil!! Thanks for your blog. I can successfully draw navigation path on GoogleMap but I want that it will also show real time position as moving on path via GPS. you can get an Idea which navigation I am talking about with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL&hl=en) do you have any tutorial or references where I can get this task done. also want to implement point 3 in OP.